# I can´t plot a map with "geom_sf()" in R

Tags: r, r-sf

First of all, sorry for my english, this is not my first language.

I'm trying to plot a map from a geometric variable with **geom_sf()**. I was able to do this in my older computer, with an older R version, but now I have the 4.0.3 version and I can´t. This is the code i use:

```
secciones <- st_read("Procesos electorales Cuauhtémoc/Secciones/SECCION.shp")

secciones <- secciones %>% 
  filter(entidad == 9 & municipio == 15)

secciones <- secciones %>% 
  select(distrito_l,seccion,geometry)

secciones %>% 
  ggplot()+
  geom_sf()
```

And this are the errors every time i run the last part of the code:

*Error: node stack overflow*

*In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)*

*Error during wrapup: node stack overflow*

*Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart*

I don´t know what is happening, I have tried uninstall older R versions, reinstall "SF" again, but the same error appears.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Shouldn't be `ggplot(df,aes(x=Latitude,y=Longitude))+geom_sf()` or something like that?

Comment: The ggplot call looks fine. The `data` argument is piped in and `geom_sf` automatically selects the geometry column if it's present in the dataset. Can you reproduce the problem with different data? Can you recreate the problem with a minimal working example?

Comment: Double check to make sure you actually have a "geometry" column. I believe `st_read` imports .shp  geometries as "geom". If you so have a "geometry" column, I find it helps to specify the data in `geom_sf`.  Try `ggplot() + geom_sf(data=secciones)`.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is likely caused by another application setting the PROJ_LIB env variable. Execute this command in R to unset the variable

`Sys.unsetenv("PROJ_LIB")`

After running that, your code should work as is.

Source: https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/2271

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).